# Too much RAM consumption

Tags: ram

I've been looking around but can't find the answer I'm looking for so here I am. I'm a newbie at Linux so bear with me. Running Ubuntu 18.04. Linux kernel 5.0.0.31. Boot up, nothing running, and I'm at 1.90 gigs of RAM after about five minutes. Any reason why this distro consumes much of my memory? Is this normal? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this: https://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Comment: GNOME, like windows 10, is written using development tools that do everything at run-time and are more resource hungry during operation. If it's an issue, Ubuntu users have plenty of choice, so use a different desktop/GUI.

Comment: Yeah I know that it's gonna require more RAM than some others but I've tested out Linux Mint and Parrot OS and they consumed roughly 800 MB RAM each. So that's why I asked. I only have 4 Gigs Of RAM. I'll switch it up later if I feel like but right now it's not really interfering with anything. And yes guiverc the options seem limitless when it comes to Ubuntu/Debian/Linux. So glad I trashed windows. :D

Comment: That clarifies things Michal Przybylowicz . Thanks.

Comment: Open System Monitor which displays all running applications. Sort the display according to Memory column and you'll get to see which processes are taking the maximum ram.